# HTML 5 Canvas keep aspect ration

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a 2D game in HTML5 and Javascript. The target is a Windows 8 app. I want to code the canvas so that on every monitor the player can't see more or less of the game. I can't seem to get anything to work...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make everthing scale with your ratio and window.innerWidth

or

you can check the display stats and make it work for 99% of the users.

[w3schools browser statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)

[w3schools innerWidth innerHeight](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)